# Facebook JS SDK: what does it mean "if the person has used your app within the last 90 days"?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

The doc here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing says "When you use the iOS, Android, or JavaScript SDK, the SDK will automatically refresh tokens if the person has used your app within the last 90 days".

I wonder what kind of "use" I should do to have the token refreshed. I tried to get last name of the user with:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

but it looks it is not enough to refresh the token (i.e. the call works fine, I get the last name of the user but the access token expiry date doesn't change / update).

I also tried:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } 
 });
```

but response.authResponse.accessToken has the same expiration date.

The goal is to renew / refresh expiration without asking the user to go through a full login again.